# Redmine or Tracd to use for project management?

Tags: project-management, bug-tracking, redmine, tracd

Can anyone suggest which of the Redmine or Tracd would be a better option for project management? Currently I am planning to deploy it on a one project setup but plan to use it across multiple projects in the fututre. Which of the two is easier to deploy? I use windows. Any other software which is web based and comes with its own web server?

Thanks...

Comment: Why don't you try both for yourself and decide? IMO Redmine has better source code repository support.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you plan to do multi-project management in the future, choose redmine. With trac you can have multi-project setups as well (having a separate environment for each project), but in the end it's a workaround. Redmine has builtin support for multi-project environments.

I previously used trac to manage my projects, but I switched to redmine. I didn't find any effective way of importing all my tickets and wiki pages. Redmine uses textile markup, but trac uses markdown, so I had a couple of troubles there.

Finally, I heard that redmine has some some issues on windows. I haven't tried running redmine on that platform so you'd better give it a try or google around.

Comment: The main Redmine developer is uses Windows so it should work fine.

Comment: You have to be careful about the definition of "project".  As we've come to understand it, a Trac "project" is an instance of Trac with certain configuration.  We use "project" to mean the tasks and milestones to release something.  We manage multiple projects in Trac by filtering milestones, etc.

Comment: Some people suggest even using the component field to distinguish between different "projects". Trac is an awesome app, but at the moment is not designed to handle that task. Working around is not a solution when you have more viable options.

Answer (score 5):

We're using Redmine on a production server and till now we didn't have any problems. I have to say Redmine is really easy to use/maintain.

Answer (score 3):

Working with redmine, ON WINDOWS, and without any problem... everything works as expected out of the box...

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [Redmine](http://redmine.org/) like the other posters as it is more complete than Trac.  See also [This question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349605/what-is-a-good-project-management-software-for-many-small-projects).

Answer (score 0):

TRAC doesn't have time management support, while redmine does. So I think that Redmine would be a better options for the project management.
Redmine allow you to annotate tickets with the estimated effort, the percent of completion and you can tell that an issue depends from another to be solved. Then you can create Gantt chart with Redmine.

For these reason in my company we are thinking to switch from TRAC to Redmine.

Both are simply to be deployed.

Comment: The Trac TimeingAndEstimation plug in handles estimates and applied time quite well.  The EstimationTools plugin provides workload and burndown charts.  I'll grant you that there isn't a good Gantt chart.