# What is a good project management software for many small projects?

Tags: web-applications, project-management, time-management

I work at a smallish web agency (3 programmers, 2 project managers), we mostly make sites for marketing campaigns and also some larger sites. Most of our projects are a week, maybe two, in development. The majority of projects are only worked on by a single developer.

Up until now we've been using a spreadsheet in Google Docs to keep track of current and upcoming projects. But lately we've been feeling this is a bit imprecise, it's hard to tell the size and scope of a project just by a single cell in a spreadsheet. And looking further, as we expand, this won't be a viable option even if we make some changes to the spreadsheet.

**Most of the (admittedly few*) project/time management tools I've looked at focus more on a small number of projects with a large number of tasks. Not caring too much about who does what.**

**What we want is something that can work comfortably the other way around, many projects assigned to few developers with a handful of tickets/tasks for each project.**

I'm also having trouble finding software that gives a good overview of what is assigned to a single developer and the expected workload they will have.

**Is there such a software?**
If not, what would be a good starting point for rolling our own?

`*` *The major ones I've looked at so far are [activecollab](http://www.activecollab.com/), [redmine](http://www.redmine.org/), [fogbugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBUGZ/) and [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), right now [redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) feels to be the most fitting*

**Update:**
I've been fooling around a bit more with Redmine, and even though I've never touched Ruby before seems to be rather easy to fiddle around with. I hacked up the timesheet addon to show future work instead of completed hours in an afternoon. Now my main obstacle will be convincing our Project Managers to give it a try ;)

Comment: Matthew here from http://tasman.io. We created Tasman as an end-to-end project management app specifically for small-medium web development teams. We launched for BETA invites today so sign up if you're interested to try it out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would probably try to use something like [Redmine](http://redmine.org/) for that.  It is not project management per se, it is more forge-like software but it has time-tracking, fora, documents & files uploading, a lightweight gantt-chart and bug/issue tracker.  It is evolving quite rapidly, can even import Trac data.

Comment: I really like where redmine is going, being able to disable modules per project is especially nice. Too bad I don't know any ruby, but I guess that can be remedied...

Comment: I hope redmine can import from fogbugz. So that when I have to move out of fogbugz (when we grow more than 2 persons) we can move to redmine.

Comment: I like Redmine (the Bitnami virtual appliance version) and currently use it since last year.

Answer (score 6):

[FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/) - a plug for our host.

Comment: I haven't really figured out how to make fogbugz behave in the way I want it to, but I guess I'll have to give it a second try!

Comment: FogBugz is not meant for many small projects, but it's usable. We use it at work, and we do have many small projects - most of the pseudo-drop-downs with the list of projects are horrible! There is, also, no way for me not to see projects that I have nothing to do with.

Answer (score 3):

I would say [fogbugz](http://www.fogbugz.com). It all depends on cost though. Most of the products/apps mentioned in the question are free or open source. If cost is a problem then one of those apps would be great.

The other nice thing about [fogbugz](http://www.fogbugz.com) is they can host it for you. For such a small team you may not want to worry about hosting the other software products yourself and making sure they are backed up and all that.

Just things to think about. I have tried most of those products and settled on [fogbugz](http://www.fogbugz.com) in the end. I am also a part of a very small team and it worked great.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I work on a team of 8 people, and we have a portfolio of something like 50 projects,  and counting...

I'm using redmine and everything seems to work just fine...

Answer (score 2):

You could also look at: http://www.dotproject.net/

I used it a couple of years ago and it wasn't too shabby.

Answer (score 1):

[Basecamp](http://basecamphq.com/)... for sure!

Suffice to say I got a non-techie team on it and they're loving life now! We, techies, have loved for months!!! :D

Answer (score 1):

If, by chance, your team were comfortable with using Emacs, then org-mode (http://orgmode.org/) would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

What about RationalPlan?

Single Project Version, Multi Project Version and Free Project Viewer:

http://www.RationalPlan.com

Ioan Lucian

Answer (score 0):

Been hearing a lot of hype about [playnice.ly](http://playnice.ly/), might be nice to see how it stacks up against some of the more established software like the [gemini project platform](http://www.geminiplatform.com)